# Control permissions for the site mailbox app

Tags: permissions, 2013, site-mailboxes

There is a SharePoint Site with a Site Mailbox App. How can one control who has access to this app? Can permissions be changed/broken? If permissions cannot be changed which permissions are inherited from parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, this app inherits permissions from the site hosting it. Check article on [SharePoint Mailbox App permissions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-suite-help/prepare-for-using-site-mailboxes-in-office-365-HA103834109.aspx):

*Task: Read, organize, reply to, or delete email from the site mailbox in SharePoint.*

Who:

- Anyone in the default owners group or the default members group for the site (**anyone with Contribute permissions**) can use the site mailbox from SharePoint. People can be listed in the owners or members group as individuals or as part of a security group.
- External team members can’t access a site mailbox.
- Each person must have a license for both SharePoint and Exchange in the same Office 365 subscription.